# Use UV map as stencil for physical model

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am in the process of creating a physical model. So I decided it would be best for me to create my shapes in Blender first so I have all the messurements I need. I am now done with the model and wondering if I can project the parts onto a UV map with correct messurements. The goal is to have a UV map that I can print out and use as a sort of stencil that will make it easier to physically cut out the parts. Otherwise, I would have to write down the measurements of each part and use those to create my model.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at Export Paper Model Addon. You can enable it in the preferences (Edit->Preferences). Search for it by name in the Add-ons section.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will have to adjust the model a bit but that should do the trick.